# How to call data from a table associated with a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I'm kind of new to RoR so this may be a stupid question, but is there
any way to pull data associated with one controller into a form in the view of
another?

I have 2 controllers, `home` and `subjects` and I have one model `subject` (probably a poor choice in hindsight). I have a table in my database called `subjects` and a column in that table called `text` I want to pull data from that column into both my `home` and `subjects` views and i can do it fine in the `subjects` view but i can't get it to work in the `home` view.

 I'm doing it with 
`def index` 
    `@subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")` 
`end`

in the subjects controller, and

`<tr>`
     `<th>Text</th>` 
      `<td><%= @subject.Text %></td>` 
    `</tr>` 

in the view.

Let me know if you need any more information, Thanks.

Comment: sorry to be a pain but can you add a bit more info about your two models please? Preferably using the names you've given them in your app, thanks.

Comment: yes thanks, I answered below, I think it will help. let me know if it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your view

```
<% for subject in @subjects %>
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th> 
    <td><%= subject.text %></td> 
  </tr> 
<% end %>
```

Note that I am using `subject` as opposed to `@subject` inside the loop, and that `.text` is not capitalised as in your code

Comment: you are my favorite person :) it worked perfectly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are only associated to tables by convention.

Models are associated to tables, and you can use whatever models you want in your controllers.

Comment: So if in AController's view i call the data with                     `<%= form_for(@subject, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  
 <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>         <tr>
    <th> <%= f.label(:Text) %> </th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:Text) %></td>
</tr>`            then how do i do it in the other view?

Comment: I'm calling the `@subjects` in the controller with `@subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")` but if i try to do that in the other controller it gives me an error message **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class**